# PHP Function Parameters not working

Tags: php, function, parameters, ternary-operator

This function is not generating any output other than the empty select tags.
It is supposed to automatically chose the amount of days based on the current month if there was no amount of days specified.

```
function create_day_select($month=NULL)
      {
        ($month == NULL) ? $date = 31 : $days = date("t",$month);
        echo "<select name='day'>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++){
          echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
      }
```

This function is working and I used the same syntax:

```
  function create_year_select($begin=NULL,$end=NULL){
    ($begin == NULL) ? $begin = date("Y") : $begin;
    ($end == NULL) ? $end = date("Y") + 6 : $end ;
    echo "<select name='year'>";
      for($x = $begin; $x < $end; $x++){
        echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
      }
    echo "</select>";
  }
```

Comment: I figured out the issue. I had $month = 31 instead of $date = 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do assignments inside the operator.

```
$days = ($month == NULL) ? ifvalue : elsevalue;
```

Unless you group them inside additional evaluative groups

```
$value = isset($var) ? ($foo = true) : ($bar = false);
```

Comment: $days = ($month == NULL) ? ifvalue : elsevalue;

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$days = ( $month == NULL ) ? 31 : date("t",$month);
```

Comment: $days = ( $month == NULL ) ? 31 : date("t",$month);